# Slow COUNT(*) Query takes longer than 1 second to execute, how can I make it faster?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM Table1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2
USING ( col1 ) 
WHERE T1.col1 !=  '1'
AND T1.col2
IN (
'A',  'A-B'
)
AND T1.col3 =  'X'
AND T2.col11=  '1'
AND T1.col4 =  'YZ'
```

This query takes over **1 second** to execute.  If I replace `COUNT(*)` with `SELECT(*)`, it also takes over **1 second**.  However, if I then also add `LIMIT 0,30` at the end, it executes in just **0.02 seconds**.

I have an index on all columns in the `WHERE` clause.  I even have a **Composite Index** in `Table1`.

Below is the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` of this query:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  T1  ref PRIMARY,col4,col3,col2,col1,CompositeIndex...   CompositeIndex1 2   const   2010    100 Using where
1   SIMPLE  T2  eq_ref  PRIMARY,CompositeIndex1,incomeLevel PRIMARY 4   T1.col1 1   100 Using where
```

**Why** is this query taking so long and **how** can I make it faster?

Comment: What is the typical `count(*)` value returned?

Comment: Can we see the table definition for both tables?

Comment: @MarkBannister: Count value returned approx. 4,100.

Comment: That's why the `select *` ... `limit 0,30` ran faster than the `count(*)` - the former only had to return the first 30 records encountered, while the latter had to count over 4,000 records. One second is not especially slow to count 4,000+ records, in a relational database.

Comment: Is `AND T2.col11=  '1'` a typo or is that correct ???

Comment: Are you using InnoDB or MyISAM tables?

Comment: @MarkBannister: 1 second actually seems like a lot.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA:  That is not a typo.  Why do you ask?

Comment: @DanielSchneller: MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you're using a `LEFT join` but requiring `T2.col11=  '1'`

Beyond that, there's not enough information to comment, except to say I hope that you don't really number your columns.

Comment: Could you please explain your first sentence, what's wrong with the way it is, and how to improve it, adn why?  (No, I don't number my columns :)  Thanks!

Comment: An inner join would produce the same results much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your original query

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM Table1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2
USING ( col1 ) 
WHERE T1.col1 !=  '1'
AND T1.col2
IN (
'A',  'A-B'
)
AND T1.col3 =  'X'
AND T2.col11=  '1'
AND T1.col4 =  'YZ'
```

You need to do two things to speed this up

## REFACTOR THE QUERY

Here is your refactored query

```
SELECT COUNT(T1.col1) FROM
(SELECT col1 FROM T1 WHERE col3='X' AND
col4='YZ' AND col2 IN ('A','A-B') AND col1<>'1') T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT col1 FROM T2 WHERE T2.col11='1') T2
USING (col1);
```

## ADD INDEXES TO SUPPORT THE SUBQUERIES

```
ALTER TABLE T1 ADD INDEX col3421_index (col3,col4,col2,col1);
ALTER TABLE T2 ADD INDEX col11_1_index (col11,col1);
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I added the Composite Index in T1 as you suggested, and I ran the refactored query above, but it took **35 seconds**.  Is there maybe something wrong with my Database?

Comment: I added an index for `T2`. Please make that index and try again.

Comment: I added the Composite Index in T2 as you suggested, but your refactored query still took over **30 seconds**.  What's strange is that each subquery if run by themselves take less than **0.01 seconds**, so why would joining them take about **2,000x longer**?  That's what makes me think there might be an issue with my Database and/or Tables.  What do you think?

Comment: It may have to due with what data is collected in temp tables. I am changing the `SELECT COUNT(*)` to `SELECT COUNT(T1.col)`. Try again and see if that is different.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of doing `SELECT COUNT (col1)`, but it still took over **30 seconds**.  It just doesn't make any sense to me that your solution takes so long when the individual subqueries it's made up of are **lightning fast**.  Any other ideas?  I'll willing to try **anything** to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Question: With the new indexes created, does your original query run any faster ???